# CentOs/Dovecot/Postfix not receiving email from outside

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos7

I'm trying to set up my mail server but I'm having some problems with Postfix.
In particulare i'm not able to receive email from external.

This is the content of my /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
myhostname = mail.paolo9785.com
mydomain = paolo9785.com
relay_host = paolo9785.com
myorigin = paolo9785.com
home_mailbox = mail/
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
inet_interfaces = localhost
mydestination = mail.paolo9785.com, localhost.paolo9785.com, localhost, paolo9785.com
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/server.crt
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1


smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service,
check_policy_service  = unix:private/policy
policy_time_limit = 3600

#DKIM config

smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
non_smtpd_milters       = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action   = accept
milter_protocol         = 2
```

Here my master.cf

```
cat /etc/postfix/master.cf
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

submission     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}


dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

policy unix - n n - 0 spawn user=nobody argv=/bin/python /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
```

at the moment there is one user set (info@...).

```
systemctl status postfix -l
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-07-24 21:53:04 CEST; 15min ago
  Process: 6591 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6650 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6644 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6632 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6972 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─ 1751 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─ 6972 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─ 6981 pickup -l -t unix -u
           ├─ 6982 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─20770 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -s 2
           ├─20776 proxymap -t unix -u
           ├─20804 anvil -l -t unix -u
           ├─21475 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
           ├─21750 cleanup -z -t unix -u
           └─21778 local -t unix

Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/trivial-rewrite[21475]: warning: do not list domain paolo9785.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/smtpd[20770]: warning: restriction check_policy_service must be followed by transport:server
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/smtpd[20770]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ua0-f181.google.com[209.85.217.181]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration error; from=<XXXXXXXX@gmail.com> to=<root@paolo9785.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ua0-f181.google.com>
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/cleanup[21750]: 9C4A85EE6A: message-id=<20170724200723.9C4A85EE6A@mail.paolo9785.com>
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/qmgr[6982]: 9C4A85EE6A: from=<double-bounce@mail.paolo9785.com>, size=1382, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/smtpd[20770]: disconnect from mail-ua0-f181.google.com[209.85.217.181]
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/trivial-rewrite[21475]: warning: do not list domain paolo9785.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/trivial-rewrite[21475]: warning: do not list domain paolo9785.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/local[21778]: 9C4A85EE6A: to=<root@paolo9785.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/qmgr[6982]: 9C4A85EE6A: removed

systemctl status dovecot -l
● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-07-24 20:49:26 CEST; 1h 28min ago
 Main PID: 24904 (dovecot)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
           ├─ 2108 dovecot/imap-login
           ├─ 2500 dovecot/imap
           ├─24904 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
           ├─24927 dovecot/anvil
           ├─24928 dovecot/log
           ├─24932 dovecot/config
           ├─29697 dovecot/auth
           ├─30635 dovecot/imap-login
           └─32508 dovecot/imap

Jul 24 21:58:03 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3-login: Login: user=<info@paolo9785.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=5.102.9.124, lip=164.132.225.73, mpid=9533, TLS, session=<adD1oRVVZAAFZgl8>
Jul 24 21:58:04 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3(info@paolo9785.com): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/1, size=737
Jul 24 22:08:34 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3-login: Login: user=<info@paolo9785.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=5.102.9.124, lip=164.132.225.73, mpid=18393, TLS, session=<PfCKxxVVnAAFZgl8>
Jul 24 22:08:35 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3(info@paolo9785.com): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/1, size=737
Jul 24 22:15:02 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3-login: Login: user=<info@paolo9785.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=5.102.9.124, lip=164.132.225.73, mpid=22021, TLS, session=<txmt3hVVqwAFZgl8>
Jul 24 22:15:03 mail.paolo9785.com dovecot[24928]: pop3(info@paolo9785.com): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/1, size=737
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

all the ports are open on the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https imaps pop3s smtp ssh
  ports: 110/tcp 465/tcp 587/tcp 25/tcp 143/tcp 3306/tcp 9000/tcp 993/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Content of other config files included:

```
cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf
user = mail_admin
password = ******************
dbname = mail
query = SELECT destination FROM forwardings WHERE source='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1

cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
user = mail_admin
password = **********
dbname = mail
query = SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1

cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
user = mail_admin
password = **********
dbname = mail
query = SELECT domain AS virtual FROM domains WHERE domain='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1

cat /etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
user = mail_admin
password = ****************
dbname = mail
query = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/') FROM users WHERE email='%s'
hosts = 127.0.0.1
```

Any suggestion? 
MX records seems to be correct, also in the logs i can see that my email reached the server but was not successfully processed.
I'm trying to send an email from my gmail as you can see in the logs.

Thanks in advance your your precious help :-)

Comment: It doesn't look like a firewall or MX issue, but like a configuration error, as the logs seem to report. A message is being sent: `Jul 24 22:07:23 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/local[21778]: 9C4A85EE6A: to=<root@paolo9785.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
` - it should be postfix trying to tell you what is wrong

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure about it! it's something that i can't see on the config :-(

Comment: I also can't find any other error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least one error in the configuration:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service, check_policy_service  = unix:private/policy`

the check_policy_service parameter should folllow it immediately and not be specified as a separate option:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy`

keep it all on one line, and no '=' between `check_policy_service` and `unix:private/policy`

Comment: what is your current 'smtpd_recipient_restrictions' ? what does `postconf smtpd_recipient_restrictions` give ?

Comment: `postconf smtpd_recipient_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: undefined parameter: virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service = unix:private/policy
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: relay_host=paolo9785.com
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes`

Comment: Now i have the following error:

`Jul 24 22:48:35 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/smtpd[9394]: fatal: need service transport:endpoint instead of "="
Jul 24 22:48:36 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/master[15286]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 9394 exit status 1
Jul 24 22:48:36 mail.paolo9785.com postfix/master[15286]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling`

Comment: the second '=' needs to go. just make sure that  "smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy" is one line. no '='

Comment: Ok thanks, i removed the second = and also virtual_mailbox_limit_maps since i don't really need it.
Still not receiving.

`postconf smtpd_recipient_restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policy
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_maildir_extended=yes
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: relay_host=paolo9785.com
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: virtual_create_maildirsize=yes`

Comment: Solved! There were another error: the domain "paolo9785.com" from mydestination since it's on the virtual domains list so it was duplicated. :-)

Comment: i also need to fix smtp, since I'm new here do you think i need to open another question or can be managed here?

Comment: always keep questions separate, makes it easier for others with similar problems to find it